# Followed links colouring inconsistent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Whilst I am overall in favour of the new design, I too feel there are a few things that could be improved.  One is the colouring of followed links - it's inconsistent between the main site and meta, and just caused me some (brief) confusion within the Hot Meta Posts box.  Here's the box as displayed on the main site and meta:

[image: main site]
[image: meta]

On the main site, followed links turn darker, on meta, they turn lighter.  The different colours are fine, but it would be nice if they were consistently dark/light.

Comment: agreed, in general I would say I find the "hot meta" box to look tacky. something off-putting about the coloring... but ah, who am I some graphics?

Comment: Also, the colors are too similar. I can hardly tell the difference between them (old eyes - 56). I especially notice this in the [Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete) tab of the Tools. I can hardly tell which ones I've already voted to delete (already visited is a Big Clue, or rather it _should_ be).

Comment: How is this different? Now that I see that other question, this one looks like a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This isn't about what colours are being used.  It's the fact that followed links get darker on one site and lighter on the other.  They could be purple and green for all it matters here, so long as they both go lighter or both go darker.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: in using the term "colors" I was including Hue, Saturation, _and_ Brightness.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Indeed - but I haven't got a gripe about the "colours" involved on any single site.  I'm quite happy with both of the blues on the main site, and both of the black/grey(?) on meta.  The issue is that on one site they get darker, on the other they get brighter.  That's what makes this question different.